# Structured References: Absolute and Relative addressing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, worksheet-function, structured-references

This is a "weighted average" formula where Q14:Q21 contains the "weights"; Column C is the first column of data, and subsequent columns are D:P

I can use this formula, and fill right.  The data columns will change and the "weight" column remain the same.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!C$14:C$21,Sheet1!$Q$14:$Q$21)/SUM(Sheet1!$Q$14:$Q$21)
```

I would like to change the data to a "table" so as to be able to use structured references.  The "weights" column header is **Percent**, and the data columns are year numbers starting with **2000**.

Is there any way of entering the "Structured Reference" form of the formula, as shown below, in a single cell, and then fill right with only the first column ("2000") changing?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table3[2000],Table3[Percent])/SUM(Table3[Percent])
```

I've looked at Excel HELP and also tried searching on Google, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table3[2000],Table3[[Percent]:[Percent]])/SUM(Table3[[Percent]:[Percent]])
```

Comment: Thanks.  A nice, simple method! Wonder why not documented in Excel HELP (at least not in 2007).

Comment: It was almost a rhetorical question.  I think that style of referencing is important, and should be included either under structured references, or in the addressing modes section.  But it's not the only shortcoming of Excel help.  Thanks for the comment on the other Q.  That was a structure used before the advent of SUMIF(S) and relatives.  Must be showing my age :-)

Comment: You are correct. I was actually responding to his comment to your answer. Since you had already responded to his original question, I didn't bother to elaborate on that issue.  Although Barry did.